# How to de-serialize an entity, put it in managed context, but not persist any changes?

Tags: java, serialization, orm, persistence

I'm new to persistence and I want to do the following:

1) Load a part of database into entities and store them in a file

2) Load these entities from file, put them in managed context (so that all the @JoinColumn and @JoinTable, especially those with lazy fetch type, would work normally) and make sure that I don't accidentally update database with them.

The point of all that is that every time I start the application I don't want to call database for the table that almost never change - so I want to store them locally, preferably in a file.

While part 1) was pretty easy, I have some concerns as to part 2). I figured that loadObject and em.persist() would work fine as long as I make sure not to call em.flush().

But at one point I'd like to check if the object in database hasn't been changed. If I call persist() on my de-serialized entity, and at the same time database changed, after flushing which version would remain?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: After some more research I found that apparently em.refresh() answers the question 'which version would remain' (refresh overwrites any changes I made locally with ones made on DB).

Still, I can't get the lazy-fetch relations to work after de-serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Load a "managed" copy of this object from database.
Then update copy the properties over from the object you read from file.

You'll have a "managed" entity not yet serialized into database.

Depending on your flow of logic you can abort it before you merge it with database instance.